# Get column value used in most rows - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Let say I have a table for each egg layed with details like,

```
EggTable
 - Egg Identitfier (Name + Number)
 - Chicken Name Which Layed Egg
 - Time of Egg Came out
```

Now I want to know which Chicken layed most eggs, I am not really sure which SQL function or query can I use.

Please note, I don't want to specify any parameter. and need chicken name as output, thank you.

Comment: `Group By`, `Count`, `Max`...

Comment: @shree.pat18 Don't forget `SELECT`...

Comment: @CustomizedName Because you didn't show minimum effort to find a solution yourself.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar and yet *you* still answered it.

Comment: @podiluska Yes, but I'm not the one who downvoted ;-) Personally I know how it feels to not know where to start and thus for such simple things find it ok to answer anyway. I was just trying to explain why *someone* might have downvoted/close-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumOfEggs, ChickenName
FROM Eggs
GROUP BY ChickenName
```

This groups the entries in the table by the chicken name and sums up how many entries there are per chicken name.

You can now select the entry with the most eggs like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 NumOfEggs, ChickenName FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumOfEggs, ChickenName
    FROM Eggs
    GROUP BY ChickenName
)
ORDER BY NumOfEggs DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) as Count, ChickenName
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ChickenName;
```